# Using tagged Classes in my entitiys - Symfony 4

Tags: symfony, controller, tags

I have init Tagged Classes in my Kernel.php

```
$container->registerForAutoconfiguration(PluginDurationInterface::class)->addTag(self::TAG_PLUGIN_DURATION);
```

I can access to all of these classes, who are tagged by self::TAG_PLUGIN_DURATION in my form Type:

```
foreach ($this->service->getTypes() as $type) {
        $id = $type->getName();
        $choices['label.duration_' . $id] = $id;
    }
```

I can also access to all of these classes in my controller class

```
foreach ($this->service->getTypes() as $state) {
            dump($state->getName());
        }
```

I have declared the service in the constructor method of controller.

But I also want, that I can access the class inside of my entity (for example in my twig template or REST API). All of the entity entries does have a value, named "duration" and does contain the name of the getName() return value.

I am using doctrine and autowiring.

Is there any way to map the duration field in my entity with the right class?

Comment: Are you trying to inject your service into entities?  Or do you want your entities to implement the duration interface?

Comment: Like @Cerad said, I'm not sure want you want to achieve. But you could use a Doctrine Event Listener with the PostLoad event to add what you want in the entity.
But in my opinion, if you just want to have shortcut in your views, you could create a TwigExtention, and in your API, you could add it with your serializer ?

Comment: No I did not have added my service in my entities at the moment. I am searching for the best way, to use my duration service in the entity result.